# Value stored in string variable got lost on each page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, variables

I have one string variable which I initialize before page load. The string variable accepting value in a function and I want to use this variable on Submit event. But when I submit the form, the string vale lost. The string variable goes blank on page load. How can I store the value till submit event?

Here is the example/sample code:

```
public partial class Send_Enquiry : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    String tempID2=string.Empty;

    ....

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void submit()
    {
        //When I am calling the "tempID2" value over here, the value come blank.
    }

    protected void getdata()
    {
        tempID2= "data";
    }

}
```

Comment: Who is calling `getData()`? Apart from that, are you aware of websites being stateless?

Answer (score 1):

Web is stateless. You need to [maintain state of your web page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.ASPX) yourself. There are many ways to do that, like `ViewState` and `Session`. You can store your string value in `ViewState` *(which is maintained at page level)* or in a `Session` which is maintained per user on server.

You can store it like:

```
ViewState["yourKey"] = "data";
```

And then for retrieving it you can do:

```
string str = ViewState["yourKey"] as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP or Web is stateless.

You'll need to save the variable into a session.

Like :

```
Session["something"]="hi";
```

You can then retrieve the value by doing this

```
string value=Session["something"]; //"hi"
```

**Websites are not like desktop applications.**

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a session variable.  To store it you'd use:

```
Session["tempId2"] = tempId2;
```

Then to get it again:

```
string tempId2 = Session["tempId2"].ToString ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class instance gets created and destroyed for each interaction (each time page is resubmitted to server).  That's why value of the field is not retained.  You should put it in the form's hidden field to retain value (implication is that the string will be visible to the client if one to look at html source).